# Insert on conflict (upsert) on table with shared column names

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables t1 and t2, both with a timestamp column called `ts`. Table t1's `ts` has hourly timestamps and the table t2's `ts` has daily timestamps. t1 represents data aggregated hourly and t2 represents data aggregated daily.
On table t2, I have a unique constraint on the `ts` column, to allow the upsert on unique constraint violation for `ts`.

I upsert data from t1 into t2:

```
insert into t2
select time_bucket('1 day', ts) as bucketed_ts, first(some_value, ts) first_some_value
from t1
group by bucketed_ts
on conflict (ts)
do update 
set 
  some_value = excluded.some_value;
```

In this case considering that both the tables have the same `ts` column with different granularity of timestamps, I wanted to understand which column the `ts` in the on conflict clause refers to - t1 or t2. If it refers to t1's ts, I shall have to use the `bucketed_ts` instead of the raw `ts` because the granularity of t1's `ts` is hourly and the desired granularity is daily.

Comment: I think you are looking for `set some_value = excluded.some_value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ON CONFLICT (ts)
```

refers to the table where the row is to be inserted (`t2`), since a unique constraint violation can only occur on that table.